# Coffeescript create new instance of a class given an object of that class

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

In coffeescript, I have an object created from a class.  Later, I no longer have access to that class, but I would like to create a new instance.  For example:

```
# MySingleton.coffee

class MySingleton
module.exports = new MySingleton
```

and then:

```
# MySingletonTests.coffee

mySingleton = require './MySingleton'

# testSingleton = ???
# I would like to create a new MySingleton here
```

I think I would like to use something like JS's Object.create here, but if I call `Object.create(mySingleton)` it seems to just make a reference to the old object, and `mySingleton.prototype` is `undefined`

**EDIT**:
I know I could just export the class in this example, but I was hoping not to because it is a singleton in production code and I would like to make sure it doesn't get new'd, but in my unit testing I would like to make new copies of it so state doesn't persist between tests

Comment: The literal definition of a singleton is *it only ever has one instance*...

Comment: Also, you should never need Object.create. If you can't reach a class to create an instance, you need to import it with the require or import keyword. If that class is a singleton, you'll just get a reference to the existing instance, but that's because it's a singleton...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out `new myInstance.constructor()` does exactly what I wanted to do.